# How can I show that the following function is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

For $0\leq t_1<t_1<...<t_n \leq 1$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we define $$\pi_{t_1,...t_n}:(C[0,1],\mathbb{B}(C[0,1]))\to (\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)), \quad x\to (x(t_1),...,x(t_n)).$$
$\mathbb{B}(C[0, 1]) := \sigma(G \subseteq C[0, 1] : G \text{ is open})$

How can I show that $\pi_{t_1,...t_n}$ is measurable?

My thinking:
I know that it is enough to show measurability on the generating set $\mathbb{R^n}$. I can write $$\pi_{t_1,...t_n}^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subseteq \mathbb{B}(C[0,1]).$$ This is equivalent as $$\{x\in C[0,1]|\pi_{t_1,...t_n}(x)\in\mathbb{R}^n\}=\{x\in C[0,1]|(x(t_1),...,x(t_n))\in \mathbb{R}^n\}.$$ 
I would say that this set is, by definition of $x$, a subset of $C[0,1]$, therefore also a subset $\mathbb{B}(C[0,1]).$

Is this the right way of thinking and more importantly, am I even understanding it correctly? Am I missing something?

Comment: How is $\mathbb{B}(C[0,1])$ generated?

Comment: @d.k.o. It is generated as folows: $\mathbb{B}(C[0, 1]) := \sigma(G \subseteq C[0, 1] : G \text{ is open})$

Comment: Then, the coordinate maps are continuous (in the sup norm, which is typically used in these settings)...

Comment: @d.k.o. Would you please elaborate a little more on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the space $C[0,1]$ with the sup norm: $d(f,g):=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$ and the topology on $C[0,1]$ induced by that norm - $\mathcal{O}(C[0,1])$. The $\sigma$-algebra under question is $\mathcal{B}\equiv\sigma(\mathcal{O}(C[0,1]))$. Then every continuous function on $[0,1]$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{B}$ ($\because$ such functions belong to $\mathcal{O}(C[0,1])$). Therefore, it suffices to show that $\pi_{t_j}$, $j=1,\ldots,n$ is continuous.